# A way to express function $g\in C^2$ by some functions $f_i\in C^1$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-derivative

**The problem**:

Let $x_i$ be the $i^{\text{th}}$ component of $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $U$ be a neighbourhood of the origin ${\bf0}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $g\in C^2(U), g({\bf0})=0$. Prove that $g$ can be expressed as the following form:
$$g({x})=\sum_{i=1}^nx_if_i({x}), $$
where $\forall n>i\in\mathbb{Z}$, $f_i\in C^1(U))$ satisfies $f_i({\bf0})=\dfrac{\partial g({\bf0})}{\partial x_i}$.

---

I tried Taylor polynomial of $g$ at the origin in $2^{\text{nd}}$ order, which is
$$g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}({\bf0})x_i+\dfrac{1}{2}x^{\mathrm T}D^2g(\theta x)x, \theta\in(0,1). $$
And it gives that
$$g(x)=\left(Dg({\bf0})+\dfrac{1}{2}x^{\mathrm{T}}D^2g(\theta x)\right)x, $$
however, $f_i(x):=Dg({\bf0})+\dfrac{1}{2}x^{\mathrm{T}}D^2g(\theta x)$ is not $C^1$.

---

The required form is similar to the total differential
$$\mathrm dg(x)=\nabla f(x)\mathrm dx=\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_i}\mathrm dx_i. $$
I also tried to integrate this formula, but it seemed not make sense to me.

Comment: you just have to integrate the right thing. [See this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3780598/568204)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks!