# Proof of Hadamard's lemma

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I do not know where to begin to prove this lemma, someone who can guide me.

Prove Hadamard's lemma:
If $f\in C^{1}(I^m,\mathbb{R})$ and $f(0)=0$, there exist functions $g_1,\ldots,g_m\in C\left(I^m,\mathbb{R}\right)$
such that
\begin{equation*}
f\left(x_1,\ldots,x_m\right)=\sum_{i=1}^mx_ig_i\left(x_1,\ldots,x_m\right)
\end{equation*}
in $I^m$, and in addittion
\begin{equation*}
g_i(0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(0),\:\:\:i=1,\ldots,m
\end{equation*}

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Do you know what $C^{(1)}$ means?

Comment: There is an error in your formatting - you have $$x^,$$ where I think you mean $$x^1,$$

Comment: Do you know this statement in dimension $1$ ? What is $I$ ?

Comment: Here is one proof strategy: Apply the Taylor's theorem to $t\mapsto f(t\mathbf{x})$ and study the remainder term in the integral form.

Comment: See [Possibly a variation of the increment theorem for functions of multiple variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3780598/568204) (just put $F(a)=0,a=0$ in that answer)