# 'Taylor expansion' but exact version of it

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Given $f(x):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ a smooth function for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider a point $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x_i$ and $p_i$ denote their $i$-th component with respect to the standard basis. I am trying to find $n$ functions $g_i(x):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x)-f(p)=\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-p_i)g_i(x)$$
and in particular $g_i(p)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_{x=p}$.

I roughly remember that $g_i$ must be an integral of something but currently could not work it out. It would be helpful if someone could remind me of what it is.

Comment: If $n=1$, $p=0$, and $f(p)=0$ then you are asking for $f(x)=xg(x)$, in which case the only reasonable candidate is $g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) / x & \quad\text{if $x \ne 0$} \\ f'(0) &\quad\text{if $x=0$}  \end{cases}$.

Comment: See [Possibly a variation of the increment theorem for functions of multiple variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3780598/568204). It’s just the chain rule and single-variable FTC.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the thread I've been looking for!

Comment: Furthermore, by writing $F(x)-F(a)=(F\circ\gamma)(1)-(F\circ \gamma)(0)$ as a finite Taylor-expansion, using say the integral form of the remainder, you can get a higher-order version of this statement.