# Extending fundamental theorem of calculus to multivariable case in a different form

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My prof. gave a classroom problem that stumped me. We're supposed to prove that if $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function, then
$$F(x)=F(a)+\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i-a^i)\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}(a)$$
The hint he gave was start with the 1-dimensional case, convert the integral into one with limits from $0$ to $1$, and then we'll get the 1-dimensional version of what we're trying to prove. Then we have to extend it to $n$-dimensional case. My try is like this -

$$F(x)=F(a)+\int_a^xF'(s)ds$$
If I substitute $s=(x-a)t+a$, then the above becomes
$$F(x)=F(a)+(x-a)\int_0^1F'((x-a)t+a)dt$$

First problem: I am not following how the integral multiplying $x-a$ on the right is equal to $\frac{dF}{dx}(a)$.

Second problem is, even if that is the case how should I extend to the $n$-dimensional case? The most I can think of is that $n$-dimensional $F$ will have several component functions $F_1,\ldots,F_n$ - to each of which we can apply the 1-D result, but how does that get us to the final result? Please help

Comment: Either you  did not write the equation correctly or the professor did. Look carefully.

Comment: @Deane: Oh! Should it be $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}(x)$ on the far right in the first equation? Thanks for the heads up! I'm really sorry but I still am not able to get past my doubts

Comment: No, still not correct.

Comment: Here's some food for thought: If the statement you wrote is true for all $n \ge 1$, for all differentiable functions $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, and for all $a \in \mathbb R^n$, then it's true in the special case that $n=1$, and that $F(x)=x^2$, and that $a=0$. So, is it true in that case?

Comment: @TedShifrin: I see but I'm confused. So since we're studying Wald's relativity book in the course, I looked up in that book. There it says: "if $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$, then for each $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there exist $C^{\infty}$ functions $H_i$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $F(x)=F(a)+\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i-a^i)H_i(x)$. Furthermore we have $H_i(a)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{x=a}$." I had tried to compare that to the Taylor expansion expression (there should be a factor of $1/2$ in the last term for a first order approximation).

Comment: That statement is correct. You’re mistaken about the $1/2$; that appears on the *quadratic* terms in the Taylor expansion.

Comment: @TedShifrin: But what I wrote (my first equation in the question) is the same as written in the book (my previous comment)? I'm sure I'm missing something and my brain probably isn't working right now. All I did was substitute the expression for $H_i(x)$ in the main equation. But based on feedback, that is still not correct whether I put $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}(a)$ or $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}(x)$ in the far right of the equation.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Thanks! so the statement I wrote in my question comes from the initial part of the Theorem 2.2.1 proof in this book (page 24 of the pdf doc = page 15 in the printed book) https://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/science_and_technology/physics/General_Relativity_Theory/General%20Relativity%20-%20R.%20Wald.pdf

If I try to plugin specific function and value you gave then I get $x^2=0^2+(x-0)H(x)$, where $H(a)=\frac{dF}{dx}\big|_{x=a}=2a$. So $x^2=x(2x)=2x^2$

Comment: You’re seriously misunderstanding the theorem’s statement. The version with $H_i$ is correct. The only extra thing they are claiming is that the function $H_i$ and the function $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}$ happen to be equal at the particular point $a$. I don’t see how you’re extrapolating from there to say $H_i=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}$ everywhere (which is what everyone above is trying to emphasize). Next, your last paragraph makes no sense. $F$ is a map $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$, so where are you getting $F_1,\dots, F_n$ from?

Comment: ^ well to be fair, the statement is true even if $F$ is vector-valued, but still

Comment: @peek-a-boo: im sorry i misunderstood - the last para should make sense if it was $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ function. i will edit the question. regarding $H_i$, how then can i get the exact form of $H_i$?

Comment: $H_i$ is equal to some integral involving partial derivatives of $F$. Why does the integral come up? Because of the FTC. Why do partials of $F$ come up? Chain rule.

Comment: ok I finally found the link to where I answered this: [Possibly a variation of the increment theorem for functions of multiple variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3780598/568204).

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you! i will read that with diligence